# create objects in object passing variables through constructor

Tags: c++, oop

Been banging my head against this all day with many trips to google.
I have a master object that needs to create several other objects in its constructor the main object gets variables in its constructor that are passed on to the objects it creates.

```
class WorldManager{
  public:
  WorldManager(int x, int y, int z){
    //do stuff
  }
}

class GameManager{
  public:
  WorldManager world;
  GameManager(int x, int y, int z){
    world(x,y,z);
  }
}
```

I get error

```
error: no matching function for call to `GAMEMANAGER::GraphicsManager(HWND__*&, int&, int&)'
```

it works untill I ask for args in the constructors of the world class

Comment: LOL, got so frustrated I forgot to add the error.

Comment: Be careful, your error message and your code seem unrelated. There's no `GraphicsManager` function or class in your code.

Comment: Thinking in terms of "manager" objects and, in general, dominance relationships between parts of the code, will probably cause you worse headaches than this little technicality.

Comment: Move all the creation code into a Factory. Pass a Configuration object to the Factory. Inside the Factory, assemble your object graph from the inside out, passing the config data only to the components that need them. Do not push the config data through the object graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
class GameManager{
public:
    WorldManager world;
    GameManager(int x, int y, int z) : world(x, y, z) { }
};
```

The weird colon thing is called an initialization list, and it does construction of member objects and parent classes and a bunch of other things.

---

If you have more than one object that you want to construct, add them to the list:

```
class GameManager{
public:
    WorldManager world1, world2;
    GameManager(int x, int y, int z) : world1(x, y, z), world2(x, y, z) { }
};
```

Comment: @billz, I can't see why not, can you elaborate ?

Comment: I have 3 classes I am creating

Comment: @billz I'm fairly certain this is what they're looking for.

Comment: @FreakinaBox Go look up how initialization lists work, you can initialize multiple objects with them. I'll add to the answer, though.

Comment: @billz that part of the question (the error message) wasn't there till later on.

Comment: @billz but there's no GAMEMANAGER in the code. Also this definitely solves a problem in the code, if not the problem that FreakinaBox was asking about.

Comment: I have this class defined in a header file. would I include the initialization list in the header file also?

Comment: @FreakinaBox The initialization list should go wherever your constructor is defined. So, if you have a `.cpp` file, it should probably go there.

Comment: got some more errors to work out before I can tell if that works. so far the errors from this have disappeared. thanks!

Comment: @FreakinaBox You put the initialization list whereever you implement the constructor, which can be in the header or in the source file.