# How to create parameterized constructor of a class in another class as a data member?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

In below example,

```
class Car
{
        private:
                int sides;

        public:
                Car()
                {
                        cout<<"\ndefault called constructor";
                }
                Car(int nsides)
                {
                        cout<<"\ncalled constructor";
                        sides=nsides;
                }

};

class Auto
{
        private:
                Car ch;
        public:
        Auto(int a) : Car(a)
        {

                //Car test(5);
        }
};

int main()
{
        Auto at(5);
        return 0;

}
```

After referring below links :-

[create objects in object passing variables through constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538547/create-objects-in-object-passing-variables-through-constructor)

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9746/

I tried to write the same and execute it.unfortunately I am getting following compiler error :-

```
check.cpp: In constructor ‘Auto::Auto(int)’:
check.cpp:44: error: type ‘Car’ is not a direct base of ‘Auto’
```

If solution mentioned in the given links are correct then what wrong in my code ? My next query is ...why only parametrized constructor() throws compiler if try to initialize it without using initialization list.

This will throw compiler error :-

```
class Auto
{
        private:
                Car ch(5);
        public:
        Auto(int a)
        {

        }
};
```

But this does not :-

```
class Auto
{
        private:
                Car ch;
        public:
        Auto(int a)
        {

        }
};
```

Please help me in understanding this behaviour.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In your example you are specifying by your constructor `Auto(int a) : Car(a)` that Auto is derived from Car, and that's what the compiler complains about.

To initialize your Car object (inside of Auto), do this `Auto(int a) : ch(a)`. You put the type instead of the member's name.

About your second question, *in-class member initialization* is a new feature brought by C++11. You may use it by adding the parameter `-std=c++11` to your compiler (GCC or Clang, msvc doesn't support it). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482566/has-in-class-member-initialization-feature-made-into-c11). In your case you can use it as chris pointed out :

```
class Auto {
// ...
Car ch{5};
int someVal = 5;
// ...
};
```

Comment: Even so, you can't do `Car ch(5);`, you need `Car ch{5};`.

Comment: But i am allowed to do the following :-
`private:`
    `Car ch;`

so why compiler does not throw error for this case.(not using -std=c++) ??

Comment: `private: Car ch;` means your instances of `Auto` will own a `Car` object. When such object is created, it will create automatically the members of the class, with the default constructor (in the case of `Car ch`, it will call `Car()`). But if you want to create you `Car ch` with a particular constructor, like `Car(int nsides)`, you have to either use in-class member initialization as chris commented, either specify the constructor you want (`ch(5)`) after the signature of the `Auto` constructor. Long story short : `Car ch;` calls default constructor, other options call specific constructors.